# Insert And Update Statement With Merge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, merge

I am attempting to execute the below syntax and I get two errors

> A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).
>     Incorrect syntax near '='.

Now if I comment out the last line of code which is an update statement the syntax executes perfectly.  Is there a way to run both an `Insert()` and `Update()` statement in one `Merge()`

Here is syntax

```
MERGE INTO EmpSales es
USING (
    SELECT employee, COUNT(sales) as SaleCount
    FROM salesInfo
    WHERE [Sale Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
    GROUP BY employee
) cs
    ON es.employee = cs.employee
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET es.TotalSales = cs.SaleCount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (employee, TotalSales)
  VALUES (cs.employee, cs.SaleCount)
  UPDATE SET es.Madrigal = '0';
```

Comment: Your `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause cannot contain an `UPDATE` clause. You need a semi-column after the `VALUES` clause;

Comment: Can I run both an update and an insert in the WHEN NOT MATCHED?  That is what I am wanting to do

Comment: If you want to set `es.Madrigal` to "0" for all records, it needs to be a separate statement. If you're trying to update the record(s) you just inserted - why not just `INSERT (employee, totalSales, Madrigal) VALUES (cs.employee, cs.SaleCount, '0')`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish. However, it seems most likely that you're trying to update `EmpSales.Madrigal` to `'0'` after your insert.

To set `EmpSales.Madrigal` to `'0'` for all newly inserted records:

```
MERGE INTO EmpSales es
USING (
    SELECT employee, COUNT(sales) as SaleCount
    FROM salesInfo
    WHERE [Sale Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
    GROUP BY employee
) cs
    ON es.employee = cs.employee
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET es.TotalSales = cs.SaleCount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (employee, TotalSales, Madrigal)
  VALUES (cs.employee, cs.SaleCount, '0')
;
```

To set `EmpSales.Madrigal` to `'0'` for all inserted or updated records:

```
MERGE INTO EmpSales es
USING (
    SELECT employee, COUNT(sales) as SaleCount
    FROM salesInfo
    WHERE [Sale Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '12/31/2016'
    GROUP BY employee
) cs
    ON es.employee = cs.employee
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET es.TotalSales = cs.SaleCount, es.Madrigal = '0'
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (employee, TotalSales, Madrigal)
  VALUES (cs.employee, cs.SaleCount, '0')
;
```

If you're looking for something else, please clarify what you need.